# how to get wordpress user id when user register

Tags: wp-query, wp-register-script

im creating wordpress user using `wp_create_user()` function and when user creating i want to add that users userid to custom table,

this is the way i tried

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'atuser_info');
function atuser_info( $user_id ) {          
    global $wpdb; 
    //$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;                
    $query_userinfo = "INSERT INTO user_info (id,fname,lname,address_1) VALUES      (".$user_id.",".$_POST['fname'].",".$_POST['lname'].",".$_POST['address_1_step2'].")";
    $wpdb->query($query_userinfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wp_create_user` executes successfully, it will return the id of the created user. [[Codex]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user#Returns)

Here it is in action with an error handler.

```
$user_id = wp_create_user();

if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
    echo $user_id->get_error_message();
} else {
    //add into custom table
    echo $user_id;
}
```

Comment: i am creating user from front end and i want to get user's Id which the user will get...how can i do so?????

Comment: Please open a new question so we can go more in-depth with your problem. But it seems this answer should be the solution you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
// $user_login is the username
// $user_email is the email address

$user_id = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);

if( $user_id ) {
echo $user_id;
// add to your database
}
else {
echo $user_id->get_error_message();
}
```